# How to create an action where would be a form for sign in/up with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am building a mobile version of our website and I would need to create a different views for sign up/in for mobile users. These two actions should be in a different controller.

My problem is that I don't know how to prepare instances for sign up/in for Devise in a different controller(s)...

How to make that?

Thanks

Comment: why not patch `Devise::RegistrationsController`?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to implement sign up/in in your own controller?

If so, you can modify routes.rb first

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "controllername" }
```

And modify the controllername_controller.rb

```
class ControllernameController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    # your implementation
  end

  def destroy
   # your implementation
  end
end
```

Comment: But this will overwrite the original Devise set up, or no? I need to keep the original Devise routes setup and add my own pages for sign up/in.